# Visual Studio user cache

Tags: c#, visual-studio, caching, visual-studio-2017, syncfusion

When developing my project in VS, I am using Syncfusion's tools to make a ribbon and support docking. While editing the ribbon with the "Customize Ribbon" dialogue, the program crashed. Now when I try opening the program. I get this error:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Root element is missing.
```

Here is the output from the Debug Console:

```
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\Analyze 2017.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Analyze_2017.App..ctor'
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'Analyze_2017.App.InitializeComponent'
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\Syncfusion.Tools.Wpf.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\SciChart.Charting.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\SciChart.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\SciChart.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\Syncfusion.SfSkinManager.WPF.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\kiddi\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.7564\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\Syncfusion.Shared.Wpf.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'SciChart.Core&'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x2734 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\AvalonDock.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\Syncfusion.Themes.Blend.WPF.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\SciChart.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsFormsIntegration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Luna\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Luna.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in Analyze 2017.exe
Downloaded valid unpacking rules from https://raw.githubus10000ercontent.com/RevolveNTNU/Telemetry-unpacking-rules-2017/master/parsing.cs?token=AVaK2e3AkDmrF7Ypd7KRW8qImovRfKs4ks5YjzTdwA%3D%3D
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\kiddi\AppData\Local\Temp\keucrxun.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\git\RevolveAnalyze2017\Revolve Analyze\Analyze 2017\bin\Debug\LiteDB.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Analyze 2017.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Analyze 2017.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

I think what happened is that I managed to create a new element in the ribbon, that does not exist anywhere else except in my user cache. I've tried to delete some of the caches in e.a. appdata and the local appdata. I have also tried reinstalling VS (RC 2017).

I have tried re-cloning the project and re-installing VS, but nothing seems to work. I am also able to run the project on a different PC.

There is probably an easy solution to my problem, but I cannot seem to find it after some hours of searching around. I'd be happy to be refereed to the an external website if it exists :)

Comment: You probably just need to delete and recreate the file in question (take a backup of it first so you can copy the content in using notepad or something).

Comment: I have already tried to re-clone the project, but it did not work

Comment: I think you should contact SyncFusion support.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Forwarding Syncfusion's answer here if anyone was wondering:**

> As you have mentioned that you are facing the exception while using
>   Ribbon control in your application, we need to analyze the features of
>   Ribbon which has been used in your application. This may help us to
>   narrow down the issue from our side. Also, we suspect that have set
>   “AutoPersist” property as true for Ribbon as you mentioned that your
>   problem is related to local cache. If so, then Ribbon state has been
>   saved in below location in “.dat” format.
>
> ```
> Location: C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\
> ```

*What I ended up doing was deleting all the contents of the IsolatedStorage. It worked perfectly. Thanks to Syncfusions excellent customer service!*

Answer (score 0):

Ifthe usual visual studio stuff doesn't work you'll have to try Syncfusion's support (it looks quite specific to them).

The usual Visual Studio stuff ...

1. Remove the file, create a new one, copy the content from the old one
   in.
2. Recreate the project.
3. Rollback (using version control tools)

Hard to say how else we could help on here without knowing a lot more about what's actually going on under the hood here (which the Syncfusion guys should be able to look at for you).